# Factorization of graphs vs factorization of trees

Tags: graph-theory

I know trees are a very particular kind of graph, a subset of the set of graphs. I would like to know in which way factorization of graphs relates to factorization of trees. Are there theorems regulating the translation from the results in one of the domains into the other, and viceversa? I am particularly interested in the answer regarding binary branching trees.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussion of factorization of graphs concerns regular graphs, and with a couple of trivial exceptions, trees are not regular, so this will not translate. Trees (with any edges) are guaranteed to have nodes of degree 1 so can have at most one factor, which means that only a tree where all the vertices are degree 1 can be "factored" (trivially: into itself) - $P_2$, the path graph of degree 2.

Given that only one factor can be extracted from any tree, which is a perfect matching, the next question could be to establish which trees have this property. More general graph analysis carries over for this, although trees are still a much more limited case. This could be a new question for you to ask, if relevant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23324/discussion-on-answer-by-joffan-factorization-of-graphs-vs-factorization-of-trees).

Comment: As I had promised, here you have a link to my newly published paper.......Some edition might still take place, as it i often the case with online journals, but, for the most part, this can be taken as the final version. If you happen to read Spanish, maybe you find it useful (albeit it is not easy reading): http://revistadefilosofia.com/64-03.pdf